# Filtering array of (key,value) in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am working a piece of code in angular 1.x , where I would like to filter array of key,values.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cust"> 

<div ng-repeat="customer in customers| filter :cust['name']">
    {{customer["name"]}}
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.customers = [
    {"name":"Sathish"},
    {"name":"Ankur"},
    {"name":"Bob"},
    {"name":"Mike"},
    {"name":"chris"},
    {"name":"chrom"}
];
```

> Basically I want to filter the array based on name of customer. if I give "ch" in the input text box it should give filter and give chris and chrom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter based on cust name but cust is just a string, so not sure what you currently have is doing. Correct way would be :

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers| filter :{name : cust}">
```